# How do you write data to new row in datagridview and save to datasource?

Tags: c#, database, object

I'm a noob to programming and having a bit of trouble with an assignment. I need to write data from an object that was captured from textboxes into a new row in my Members Table datagridview and then save it to the dataset. (On VS and C#)

```
AddMember newMember = new AddMember();
newMember.firstName = Firstname.Text;
newMember.lastName = Lastname.Text;
newMember.address = AddLine1.Text;
newMember.phone = Int32.Parse(PHnumber.Text);
newMember.membershipID = comboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1;
newMember.directDebit = paymentoptionID;
newMember.paymentFrequency = paymentFrequencyName;
newMember.extras = checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices.Cast<int> ().ToArray();
```

Comment: By `save it to the dataset` do you mean the Collection in memory for the `AddMember`'s or a `Database`? 

Also, when you create the `Member` you could create a new `DataGridViewRow` and populate the `Cells` with the data from the properties that the `AddMember` object has, then insert it into the `DataGridView`'s `Rows` collection like so:

`this.dataGridView.Rows.Add(createdRow)`

Comment: I mean I want to save it to an existing database. The Members table is already populated with sample data

Comment: Have you made any attempts already at inserting a new record into the `Members` table? Can you update your question to include the Schema for the `Members` table? Also, taking a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0 will lead you in the right direction to make an attempt yourself

Comment: I've tried to look for a similar solution online but haven't been able to implement it into mine. The course I'm taking is using minimal SQL so I'm wondering if theres an easier solution using C#.

Comment: If you're looking for a way to manage the Database content with `minimal/no SQL` you could use Entity Framework (see: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/dbcontext/adding-data)

But I wouldn't say it's a very `beginner friendly` way of approaching it, I would suggest creating a method on the `AddMember` class something like: `public string ToSqlInsert()` which will return the SQL Query for inserting a new record into the table and then when performing the insert into the Database, you would just need to use `user.ToSqlInsert()` to get the SQL Command for that user if that makes sense?